# Read RZ11 parameter sapgui/user_scripting

Tags: vbscript, sap-gui

I am trying to use SAP GUI Scripting to read "current value" set for parameter "sapgui/user_scripting" via t-code RZ11. I can connect to SAP instance, login and execute RZ11 with my script. But I can't read the current value set for "sapgui/user_scripting" and print to console.

```
    self.session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "rz11"
    self.session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(0)
    time.sleep(2)
    self.session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtTPFYSTRUCT-NAME").text = "sapgui/user_scripting"
    value = self.session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtTPFYSTRUCT-TYPE").text
    print(value)
```

I am using above code. But the output in console is "sapgui/user_scripting". I need the output to be "TRUE". Please help

Comment: You can use SAP GUI Scripting only if `sapgui/user_scripting` is TRUE. If it's FALSE, there will be the Run-Time Error 614 "The enumerator of the collection cannot find en element with the specified index" in your script during access to the `GuiConnection` object, that you can intercept. Note that this `sapgui/user_scripting` is not the only condition to allow SAP GUI Scripting.

Comment: @SandraRossi I have already enabled scripting with "sapgui/user_scripting" with TRUE. And script is working because I can log in and execute t-code with script. The issue is I am not aware of how I can retrieve the value of "sapgui/user_scripting" via script and print it to console

Comment: Okay. I guess your question is more about reading any other profile parameter because it's non-sense to read a value that you know will always be TRUE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `RZ11` in my SAP version, it shows a GuiHTMLViewer object:

[image: RZ11 display profile parameter details]

It's a little bit difficult to read data from the HTML control. It can be complex also because there are 2 types of HTML controls depending on SAP GUI settings.

I recommend to find a workaround to display the value via a GUI object other than GuiHTMLViewer, like:

- clicking the button `Change Value`:

  [image: RZ11 Change parameter value]

  - The value can be obtained with this code:

    ```
    self.session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtNEW_PARVALUE").text
    ```
- or run the program `RSPARAM` (using `SA38` or `SE38`) to display values in GuiGridView control ; use the filter button in order to display only one line:
  [image: RSPARAM GuiGridView]

  - The value can be obtained with this code (the first argument 0 being the first row, followed by the column name which depends on the ABAP version):
    **7.56:**

    ```
    self.session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").getCellValue(0,"USER_VALUE")
    ```

    **7.52:**

    ```
    self.session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").getCellValue(0,"PAR_USER_WERT")
    ```

For more information, see the API documentation at https://community.sap.com/topics/gui/scripting.

Comment: Thanks for your help. That worked like a charm :). Only thing is, the column name is different, it's "PAR_USER_WERT". So the LOC for obtaining value becomes `session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").getCellValue(0,"PAR_USER_WERT")`. 
For obtaining the column name, I used GUI's script recording and increased the width of 2nd column.

Comment: Thanks. The column name depends on the ABAP version. "USER_VALUE" is in ABAP 7.56. I confirm that it's "PAR_USER_WERT" in ABAP 7.52.